# an enclosing instance is required...?

Tags: java

I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this error? It shows up for playerA, playerB, and playerC when I try to make them into an AbstractPlayerImpl. The error says "an enclosing instance is required"

```
/**
 * Test the getNextPlayer method.
 * 
 * @throws IllegalPlayerNameException thrown if the player name is invalid.
 */
@Test
public void testGetNextPlayer()
        throws IllegalPlayerNameException
{
    final AbstractTurnBasedGameImpl game;
    final PlayerNameValidator validator;
    final PlayerNameConverter converter;
    final Player playerA;
    final Player playerB;
    final Player playerC;

    validator = DefaultPlayerNameValidator.create();
    converter = DefaultPlayerNameConverter.create();
    playerA = new AbstractPlayerImpl("A",
                                     validator, converter);
    playerB = new AbstractPlayerImpl("B",
                                     validator, converter);
    playerC = new AbstractPlayerImpl("C",
                                     validator, converter);
    game = new AbstractTurnBasedGameImpl (playerA, playerB, playerC);
```

---

```
/**
 * A simple player.
 */
public class AbstractPlayerImpl extends AbstractPlayer 
{
    /**
     * Construct an AbstractPlayerImpl with the specified arguments.
     * 
     * @param nm the player name.
     * @param validator used to check the player name.
     * @param converter used to convert the player name.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalPlayerNameException if the player name is invalid. 
     */
    public AbstractPlayerImpl(
            final String nm,
            final PlayerNameValidator validator,
            final PlayerNameConverter converter) 
            throws IllegalPlayerNameException 
    {
        super(nm, validator, converter);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `new AbstractTurnBasedGameImpl(...)` compiles, it means your naming convention is exceptionally poor.

Comment: That's true... never start the name of a concrete class (not abstract) with "Abstract"!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you declaring both classes in the same file??? If so, you'd better split them up or make the nested class (ie. the one being declared inside the other) 'static':

```
static class PlayerImpl extends AbstractPlayer
```

I know you've used different names, but PLEASE don't call a concrete class a name starting with "Abstract"! Programmers use the convention of giving names starting with "Abstract..." ONLY to Abstract classes! Calling your class AbstractPlayerImpl is totally contradictory (a abstract implementation????)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying will only work if Player is a subtype of AbstractPlayerImpl. In other words, Player must extend AbstractPlayerImpl.

```
 public class Player extends AbstractPlayerImpl
```

If Player is the superclass, this won't work.

Remember, a child is like its parent; a parent is not like its child.

Comment: did you mean to declare A,B,C as AbstractPlayer?

Comment: yes. It's part of a tutorial that I'm supposed to follow... :/

Comment: Wait no. I followed the tutorial and it says to make it what I typed. I even copied and pasted just in case I was crazy.

Comment: sounds like the tutorial misled you. If this response address your issue, remember to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

"An enclosing instance is required" means an [*inner class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) has been attempted to be created in a static (or out-of-defining-outer-class) context. Inner classes -- which are a special subset of [static] nested classes -- are "bound" to a specific containing object and can thus *only* be created *in context of an applicable outer class instance*.

> Objects that are instances of an **inner class[es] exist within an instance of the outer class.**

It is likely that somewhere along the refactoring some original classes were left as inner classes and are now being used in an out-of-defining-class context: make then all normal (e.g. non-inner) classes. (Also, make sure there are no duplicate classes and any old class files have been cleaned, for sanity.)

Happy coding.

Comment: I think what I said before got deleted. I'm following a tutorial... So I don't really know what that means. The tutorial said that there isn't supposed to be any errors.

Comment: @user1251020 If the tutorial doesn't contain any errors, then some were introduced. If the **exact error message error message is included** (and the complete relevant code or *even a link to the tutorial*) then it would be possible to pinpoint exactly which line/type was in error. Please see the linked Java trail.